# How to select an element based on some criteria other element?

Tags: css, jquery-selectors

How do I select a DIV from a table that informs that it has a SPAN with a certain value and that its neighbor (before or after) must also follow the same rule?

Example:

1. Select number 1 from table 1.05, whose successor is 2.
2. Select number 1 from table 2.15, which has 2 as predecessor.

```css
.C {
  display: table;
}

.D {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        min-width: 45vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="A">
    <div class="B">Tabela 1.05</div>
    <div class="C">
      <div class="D"><span class="E">1</span> </div>
      <div class="D"><span class="E">2</span></div>
      <div class="D"><span class="E">2</span></div>
      <div class="D"><span class="E">4</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="B">Tabela 2.15</div>
    <div class="C">
      <div class="D"><span class="E">2</span> </div>
      <div class="D"><span class="E">1</span></div>
      <div class="D"><span class="E">2</span></div>
      <div class="D"><span class="E">4</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3vnh7acr/1/

Comment: You cannot use css selectors to select a parent element. The same goes for comparing content values. You would need to write code for that. Maybe try to add a class when generating your html.

Comment: And using jquery is it possible?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/